# Elasticsearch - creating index failure when doing it through java API but not manually

Tags: java, kotlin, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-api

I have a complex index with a ngram analyzer. I want to be able to create a new index through the Java API. I am currently using Kotlin for this but using the same framework. I have created the schema for this index as so:

```
 {
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "max_ngram_diff": 20,
      "search.idle.after": "10m"
    },
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "ngram3_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "ngram3_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "ngram3_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 20
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "fields": {
            "partial": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "ngram3_analyzer",
              "search_analyzer": "keyword"
            },
            "text": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        },
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_shape",
          "ignore_malformed": true
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "sort": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This json schema works when manually passing it via a rest client PUT call.

```
    {
    "acknowledged": true,
    "shards_acknowledged": true,
    "index": "new_index_created"
    }
```

Passing the same schema via elastic java API using the following koltin function:

```
private fun createIndex(index: String, schema: String) {
    val createIndexRequest = CreateIndexRequest(index).mapping(schema, XContentType.JSON)
    getClient().indices().create(createIndexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT)
}
```

I get this response:

```
Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [settings : {index={max_ngram_diff=20, search.idle.after=10m}, analysis={analyzer={ngram3_analyzer={filter=[lowercase], tokenizer=ngram3_tokenizer}}, tokenizer={ngram3_tokenizer={min_gram=3, type=ngram, max_gram=20}}}}] [mappings : {_doc={properties={name={type=keyword, fields={text={type=text}, partial={search_analyzer=keyword, analyzer=ngram3_analyzer, type=text}}}, location={ignore_malformed=true, type=geo_shape}, sort={type=integer}, type={type=keyword}}}, dynamic=strict}]]
```

any help on this issue would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is because you're passing both `mappings` and `settings` into the `mapping(...)` call.

You can either call `mapping()` with only the `mappings` section and `setting()` with the `settings` section, or you can call `source()` like this:

```
val createIndexRequest = CreateIndexRequest(index).source(schema, XContentType.JSON)
                                                      ^
                                                      |
                                                  change this
```